# Pydantic model exports - how to skip defaults, except for some fields?

Tags: python, export, pydantic

Let's say I have a model like this:

```
class A(BaseModel):
    a : int = 1
    b : int = 2  # always want to return `b`, even if it wasn't passed in.
    c : int = 3
```

I want to use `inst.dict(skip_defaults=True)`, **except that I always want to return `inst.b` regardless.**

Is there a way to do this with the Pydantic API?  I am thinking of subclassing the `dict` method instead, but I maybe don't understand the interaction between `include` and `skip_defaults`.

None of these tries worked if `inst = A(...)` did not include setting `b`.

`dict(skip_defaults=True)` - as expected

`dict(skip_defaults=True, include={'b'})`

```
class A(BaseModel):

    class Config:
        include = {"b"}

    a : int = 1
    b : int = 2
    c : int = 3
```

#### This did work, but do I really have to do this?

```
class A(BaseModel):

    a : int = 1
    b : int = 2
    c : int = 3 

    def dict(self, *args, **kwargs):
        res = super(A,self).dict(*args, **kwargs)
        res.update(b=self.b)
        return res
```

##### This seems a bit frivolous, so here's my use case.

I am using Pydantic to generate json parameters for an API - Tabulator.js.  This API has a bunch of options, many with defaults.  I don't want to unnecessarily clutter the json settings by repeating Tabulator's own defaults, so I've configured my own Pydantic models to match Tabulator's when I use those options in the first place and then I use `skip_defaults`.

But, I also want to default my own Pydantic models with options that do not match Tabulator's.  For example `{"layout": "fitColumns"}` is what I want to use by default, but I **DO** want to pass this on to Tabulator because that differs from their own default for `layout`.

```
class TabulatorColumnOptions(BaseModel):
    title : str
    formatter : str = "string"
    headerFilter : str = ""
    sorter : str = ""

class TabulatorTableOptions(BaseModel):

    # always return via `dict()`
    layout : str = "fitColumns"      
    columns : list[TabulatorColumnOptions]
```

In this case `layout` here is what I had in mind with my `b` field in my example - a field I always want to return.